# Spherical Harmonic integration

Tags: integration, spherical-harmonics

How do I solve the lower integration of spherical harmonics, in terms of Clebsch Gordon coefficients?

\begin{equation}
\int d\Omega Y^{l_1}_{m_1}(\hat n)Y^{l_2}_{m_2}(\hat n){Y^{l}_m}^*(\hat n) 
\end{equation}

As a side note, where could I find derived properties of spherical harmonics and Clebsch Gordon coefficients?

Comment: What are $Y$, $m_i$, $l_i$, $l_*$? I assume $\Omega$ is the unit sphere?

Comment: @user7530 yeah unit sphere is correct. Y is a spherical harmonic, $Y_m^l = N \exp^{im\phi} P_m ^l (cos \theta)$

Where P is the associated legendre polynomial.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics
It is given under the conventions section of quantum mechanics. 

My bad, it's $Y^*$ and not $l*$.
Thanks!

Comment: See [equation 34.3.22](http://dlmf.nist.gov/34.3#E22) of the DLMF.